# Flutter pop after async function finished

Tags: flutter

I am using the following code to pop to a homescreen after doing an async function:

```
await globals.SaveToDisk.saveQuotebank().then((value) => {
    Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/')),
});
```

The `globals.SaveToDisk.saveQuotebank()` function is:

```
static Future<void> saveQuotebank() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final quotebanks = prefs.getString('quotebanks');
  if (quotebanks == null) {
    await prefs.setString('quotebanks', jsonEncode([currentQuotebank.toJson()]));
    return;
  } else {
    final quotebanksString = prefs.getString('quotebanks');
    final quotebanks = jsonDecode(quotebanksString ?? '[]');
    quotebanks.add(currentQuotebank.toJson());
    await prefs.setString('quotebanks', jsonEncode(quotebanks));
  }
}
```

However, when I execute the top code, I get this error: Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose()

I've also tried adding a spurious second delay in the then() function but that didn't work either.

What have I done wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: either you use future then or you use async await in your code 
in this case when you write "await" the function will stop code execution until it finished then execute the remaining code 
so remove "then()" and use await only then write your pop code

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I had some code that was changing the color of something with a 2 second delay and this was causing the error.